# Find Singularity Type $\frac{f(z_0)^2+g(z_0)}{h(z_0)+r(z_0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z),g(z)$ have pole of order $1$ at $z_0$, $h(z)$ pole of order $2$ and $r(z)$ removable singularity at $z_0$

What is singularity of $$\frac{f(z_0)^2+g(z_0)}{h(z_0)+r(z_0)}$$

So I set $f(z)=\frac{a(z)}{z-z_0},g(z)=\frac{b(z)}{z-z_0},h(z)=\frac{c(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}$ can ignore $r(z)$?

$$\frac{f(z_0)^2+g(z_0)}{h(z_0)+r(z_0)}=\frac{\frac{a^2(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}+\frac{b(z)}{z-z_0}}{\frac{c(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}+r(z)}=\frac{a^2(z)+b(z)(z-z_0)}{(z-z_0)^2}*\frac{(z-z_0)^2}{c(z)+r(z)(z-z_0)^2}=\frac{a^2(z)+b(z)(z-z_0)}{c(z)+r(z)(z-z_0)^2}$$

Plug in $z=z_0$ we get:

$$\frac{a^2(z_0)+b(z)*0}{c(z_0)+0}$$

But $c(z_0)$ is analytic

Comment: "What is singularity of $$\frac{f(z_0)^2+g(z_0)}{h(z_0)+r(z_0)}$$" That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Note that\begin{align}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f^2(z)+g(z)}{h(z)+r(z)}&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\frac{a^2(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}+\frac{b(z)}{z-z_0}}{\frac{c(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}+r(z)}\\&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{a^2(z)+(z-z_0)b(z)}{c(z)+(z-z_0)^2c(z)}\\&=\frac{a^2(z_0)}{c(z_0)}\in\mathbb{C}\end{align}and that therefore your function has a removable singularity at $z_0$ if $z_0$ is *not* a zero of $c$ and a pole otherwise (whose order is the order of $z_0$ as a zero of $c$).

Comment: Why removable singularity? as $c(z_0)$ is analytic

Comment: @newhere Right. I've edited my answer.